# How can I change the menu-entry key for an Orgmode export mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I want to use (e.g.) both the Markdown and Mediawiki exports for Orgmode.  However, they both use `m` as the menu-entry key, and the behaviour seems undefined when I load both packages.

I could change this in the code, e.g. change `?m` to `?w` below to export to Mediawiki.  However, I want to do this instead in my `init.el` by setting or changing a variable after loading the package.  Can that be done, and if so, how?

```
(org-export-define-derived-backend 'mw 'html
  :filters-alist '((:filter-parse-tree . org-mw-separate-elements))
  :menu-entry
  '(?m "Export to Mediawiki"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little spelunking in the source code goes a long way. If you check the source for `org-export-define-derived-backend` (you can do this by typing `C-h f` and then typing the name of the function) you will see that all it really does is create a `backend` object and put it into a list stored in a variable called `org-export-registered-backends`.

The `backend` objects are structs defined in `ox.el` like this:

```lisp
(cl-defstruct (org-export-backend (:constructor org-export-create-backend)
                  (:copier nil))
  name parent transcoders options filters blocks menu)
```

You can see that it defines slots called `name`, `parent`, `menu`, etc. It creates accessor functions for these slots called `org-export-backend-name`, `org-export-backend-parent`, `org-export-backend-menu` and so on.

Simply write a loop over the list stored in `org-export-registered-backends` looking for the one whose name is `'mw`, and then modify its menu item. Perhaps something like this, but there are other ways to write it that you might prefer:

```lisp
(dolist (backend org-export-registered-backends)
  (if (eq 'mw (org-export-backend-name backend))
    (setf (car (org-export-backend-menu backend))
          ?w)))
```